# "mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:" not called

Tags: mkmapview

I'd like to implement the method:"mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:"... Wierdly, when i test the app (even on a device), it seems the method doesn't get called.
I have set the map view delegate, done:

```
[myMap setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow];
[myMap.delegate mapViewWillStartLocatingUser:myMap];
```

but it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to call mapViewWillStartLocatingUser yourself, it gets called if you give your mapView a delegate and then tell the map view to start showing the user's location.

Comment: Hi Pao. If my answer was correct then you should click the tick/check to the left of it so that others can easily see you accepted the answer. (it also gives me points for being right :) )